# swift dynamic constraint in UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, constraints

[image]

I add constraint manually.

Bottom of Imgv to BottomMargin of cell.contentView constraint.

Error msg....

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c99b3e0 V:[UIImageView:0x7c983370(100)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c99b4a0 UIImageView:0x7c983370.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7c987b50.topMargin>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c99b6f0 UIImageView:0x7c983370.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7c987b50.bottomMargin>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c99afd0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7c987b50(115.5)]>"

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c99b6f0 UIImageView:0x7c983370.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7c987b50.bottomMargin>
```

What's the problem ?

Comment: remove top constraint or centerY constraint and try

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 vertical constrains, only 2 of which can be active at the same time:

- height
- center vertically
- align the top of the view with the top of the cell

There's exactly one situation where they can all be true (if the cell is the same height as the view), but since your cell is higher than that, you get the conflicting constraints. If Interface Builder isn't warning you about that, I'm guessing your cell is a different size at run time.